# Why this function has both Unicode and ANSI versions?

Tags: winapi, unicode, ansi

Why does [`EndUpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648032.aspx) have both Unicode and ANSI versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `BeginUpdateResource` has (due to its LPCTSTR parameter), and the handles produced by the two versions may need different internal clean-up. (Even if they don't today, a prudent API designer will leave open the possibility that they may tomorrow).

Comment: Implementation detail leak, anyone? :-) +1

Comment: As I see it, the API specifically tries hard to _avoid_ leaking implementation details. In this case the detail it doesn't leak is whether handles created with BeginUpdateResourceA and BeginUpdateResourceW need different clean up or not. If there was only a single EndUpdateResource, it would be leaking the information that the clean-up is the same.

Comment: Isn't that what `CloseHandle` does?

Comment: `CloseHandle` closes a kernel object handle, but there are lots of APIs that return `HANLDE`s that are not really (or not purely) kernel object handles, just because then the designers would not have to define their own opaque typedef. You could argue that this constitutes a detail leak, but I would say that its a case of the API failing to expose _enough_ information when it misuses the `HANDLE` type in that way.